# How to store multiple level ul list in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, list, store

I have a long, at least 5 levels `<ul>` list i have listed from a mysql database. The user has the opportunity, to sort the items, drop one item from one list to another, rename them, or delete. Then save it.

I am using PHP for listing, and Javascript/Jquery for rearranging the items.

**My question is whats the best way to split the ul li elements into an array?** It's important to have the parent id of every element.

Very simplified sample code:

```
<a href="#">Parent item name</a>
<ul data-level='0'>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Child item name</a>
        <ul data-level='1'>
            <li><a href="#">2nd level item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2nd level item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2nd level item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2nd level item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As the result, '2nd level item 2' should have it's parent 'Child item name' (it's id is stored in a hidden input field next to it's name).

The list can be any levels, as the user can add additional levels too. The code must handle a 15 levels list too.

I was thinking about getting the value of a hidden input placed in every `<li>` element via javascript. the JQuery is capable of getting the number of children. But that doesn't seem to be the best solution.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: a single table with a parent/child foreign key self-relation, and appropriate server-side code to convert that flat table into a nested array which you json-encode and send across? actual implementation is left up to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO when submit button clicked, your jquery can iterate the list and create JSON object (that each member has parent value, 0 for root) and send it behind with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Parent item name</a>
<ul class="0" id="level_0_count_0" data-level='0'>
<li>
    <a href="#">Child item name</a>
    <ul class="1" id="level_1_count_0" data-level='1'>
        <li><a href="#">ul 0 2nd level item 1pppppppp</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ul 0 2nd level item 2pppppppp</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ul 0 2nd level item 3pppppppp</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">ul 0 2nd level item 4</a>
            <ul class="2" id="level_2_count_0" data-level='1'>
                <li><a href="#">ul 2 3nd level item 1cccccccc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ul 2 3nd level item 2cccccccc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ul 2 3nd level item 3cccccccc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ul 2 3nd level item 4cccccccc</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">Child item name</a>
    <ul class="1" id="level_1_count_1" data-level='1'>
        <li><a href="#">ul 1 2nd level item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ul 1 2nd level item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ul 1 2nd level item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ul 1 2nd level item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
var temp = new Array();
find_ul(0, temp);
});


function find_ul(parent_class, new_object_, level_count){
if( $j('.' + parent_class + ' > li > ul').length == 0){
    return new_object_;
}else{
    var current_objs = $j('.' + parent_class + ' > li > ul');
    var i = 0;
    parent_class++;
    $j.each(current_objs, function() {
            var current_ul_id = '';
            var object_lis =  $j('ul#level_' + parent_class + '_count_' + i + ' > li');
            var b = 0;
            var tempora = new Array();
            var current_ul_id = $j(this).attr('id');
            alert(current_ul_id);

           $j.each(object_lis, function() {
               tempora[b] = $j(this).html();
               b++;
               alert($j(this).html());

            });

            new_object_[i] = {ul_id: current_ul_id, lis:tempora};
            i++;

    });
}
   find_ul(parent_class, new_object_);
}
```

You can see / test it out at:
http://jsfiddle.net/BsDpY/4/

This would generate an array with levels for each layer of ul/li

so it will first go through the first level (the parents) then go through its child ULs..

Hope that helps.